# extract all possible emoticons from a python list

Tags: python, unicode, nltk, emoticons

## Objective

I am trying to extract all possible emoticons from a unicode word list. 
I am using Python3 with anaconda installation, therefore I can not use a package such as `emoji.py`.

Here is a sample bow of word list.

```
lst = ['✅','türkçe','Çile','ısp','İst','ğ','some','#','@','@one','#thing','','1','41','ç','ö','⏱','⏱','','₺','€',':)',':/']
```

Expected output is like this:

```
out = ['✅','⏱', '⏱','']
```

## Attempt 1

List comprehension to check if all chars are ASCII:

```
[w for w in lst if len(w) != len(w.encode())]
```

However, this is not giving the desired output because there are non ASCII letters in text. Also, currency symbols are not emoticons.

```
['✅', 'türkçe', 'Çile', 'ısp', 'İst', 'ğ', 'ç', 'ö', '⏱', '⏱', '', '₺', '€']
```

## Attempt 2

Using NTLK emoticons regular expression

```
from nltk.tokenize.casual import EMOTICON_RE
EMOTICON_RE.findall(' '.join(lst))
```

However, `EMOTICON_RE` can only extract expressions such as `:)` `:/` `:(`

Here is the list of what I am to considering to be [emoticons](http://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html).

I tried to build a list of emoticons to see if my word exists in that list, but I could not build a list of emoticons from unicode character codes.

Can you please suggest?

Comment: *I am using Python3 with anaconda installation. Therefore i can not use a package such as emoji.py* - I see no reason why - what's stopping you?

Comment: it does not exist in conda index

Comment: And the instructions at https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#installing-non-conda-packages don't work?

Comment: I was not aware of i could install non-conda packages. But suggested solutions works for me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that all of those characters are in *Symbol, other* [category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property). Therefore you can do

```
[w for w in lst if any(c for c in w if unicodedata.category(c) == 'So')]
```

Comment: Note 1: There are many characters in that category that are not emojis, so this could lead to false positives with text containing other symbols: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/So/list.htm

Comment: The unicodedata module in the stdlib is tied to a given Unicode version. Unicode generelly adds new emojis on every release, so using new emojis would probably cause false negatives

Comment: Thank you for the heads up. I review the list briefly. They all out of my scope. Thank you again.